# Unable to get checkstyle to find whitespace issue with post_inc

Tags: checkstyle

Working on a project where all `++` and `--` operations need whitespace padding on the left and right.  I am trying to get checkstyles to detect this, but `WhitespaceAround` doesn't seem to check this.

What would be the best way to enforce code like `i++` to be `i ++` using checkstyle?

Current code is https://github.com/dcapwell/tachyon/blob/checkstyle/core/src/main/resources/tachyon_checks.xml

Here is the current whitespace checks I have in-place.

```
<module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
<module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
<module name="MethodParamPad"/>
<module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
  <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_INIT, BNOT, DOT, LNOT, TYPECAST" />
</module>
<module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
  <property name="tokens" value="SEMI, DOT" />
</module>
<module name="OperatorWrap"/>
<module name="ParenPad"/>
<module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
<module name="WhitespaceAfter">
  <property name="tokens" value="COMMA, SEMI, TYPECAST, PLUS, PLUS_ASSIGN, POST_DEC, POST_INC, DEC, INC, UNARY_MINUS, UNARY_PLUS" />
</module>
<module name="WhitespaceAround">
  <property name="tokens" value="INC, POST_INC, DEC, POST_DEC" />
</module>
<m
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Checkstyle 5.7 documentation, [WhitespaceAround](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAround) cannot be configured to check the `POST_INC` or `POST_DEC` tokens. The same is true for [WhitespaceAfter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAfter). There is a [NoWhitespaceBefore](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#NoWhitespaceBefore) rule that can do the opposite of what you want.

You can at least configure *NoWhitespaceBefore* to stop flagging your extra spaces, as you already did.

Since there is no dedicated check that does what you want, you may want to configure a [Regexp](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Regexp) check as a last resort:

```xml
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="format" value="\w(?:\+\+|--)\W"/>
    <property name="message"
        value="Increment/Decrement operator must be preceded by space."/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

This will even ignore comments and work if there is a line break between `i` and `++`.

(I would generally advise against this kind of rule, though. Not having a space before a post-increment or post-decrement operator has been the Java style since the dawn of time, so changing this may make your code less easy to understand for others.
)